# Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('<p>[mb_board name="friends" style=""]</p>');?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('<p>[mb_board name="recommend" style=""]</p>');?>
```

Only one of the two is implemented. How do I implement both?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing both commands in the same echo statement

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('<p>[mb_board name="friends" style=""]</p>\n<p>[mb_board name="recommend" style=""]</p>');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't  you try this ??

```
<p><?php echo do_shortcode('[mb_board name="friends" style=""]');?></p>

<p><?php echo do_shortcode('[mb_board name="recommend" style=""]');?></p>
```

But make sure that your parameters for your shortcodes are correct.